# How to Check the LINQ SQL / Query its NULL or Not - MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

In my Action I have Three LINQ SQL(Join) , two of them which is `bla4,bla5` it was working until i add Third SQL which is `bla6` and `SQL(bla6)` only going to work or executed until RMAHistory table get data/value or have data in it and RMAHistory table get value/data until than user submitted the form before that all the rows is null in RMAHistory table and in my LINQ SQL (bla6) i have Join with RMAHistory and beacuse i have interesting one column of that table.

Here is my question how can i check if SQL (bla6) its null than run/execute bla4,bla5 and than return view and if SQL(bla6) its not null than run/execute (bla4,bla5,bla6) and in the return view.

I have tried to check if modal its null or not both in view and Controller ,but i get Object reference is not set to an instance of an object and it's beacuse rmah.AntalRMA is null.

Can anyone help me or point me in the right direction!
Thanks in advance :)

Controller:

```
     public ActionResult RMA(RMAHistory oodvm ,string id, string Varenummer, string OrdreNo)
     {

     var bla6 = (from sil in data.Sales_Invoice_Line

     join rmah in data.RMA_History on sil.Document_No_ equals rmah.Fakturnummer

     where sil.Document_No_ == id

     select new RMAHistory.SingelRMAAntal

     {

      TotalRMA = rmah.AntalRMA

       });

var col2 = data.Sales_Shipment_Line.Where(t => t.Order_No_ == OrdreNo).Where(t => t.No_ == Varenummer).Select
  (t => new
{
 No_ = data.Sales_Invoice_Header.Where(or => or.Order_No_ == OrdreNo).FirstOrDefault().No_,
Line = t,
Serial = data.Item_Ledger_Entry.Where(ledger => ledger.Document_No_ == t.Document_No_).Where(ledger => ledger.Document_Line_No_ == t.Line_No_).ToList(),
TrackAndTrace = data.Track_and_Trace.Where(track => track.Shipping_No_ == t.Document_No_).Select(tr => new { traceNR = tr.Track_and_Trace, tracePath = tr.Track_and_trace_path, Agent = tr.Shipping_agent }).FirstOrDefault()

 });

 var bla4 = col2.Select(t =>
         new RMAHistory.OrdreRMA
        {
          //Select something
         });

      var bla5 = (from sih in data.Sales_Invoice_Header
      join sil in data.Sales_Invoice_Line on sih.No_ equals sil.Document_No_
      join item in data.Item on sil.No_ equals item.No_
      join itemcat in data.ItemCategory on item.Item_Category_Code equals itemcat.Code
         where sil.Document_No_ == id
           &&
          sil.No_ == Varenummer
           &&
          sih.Order_No_ == OrdreNo
        select new RMAHistory.InvoiceOrdreLineSingel
      {
        //Select something
     });

        oodvm.OrdreRMAs = bla4.FirstOrDefault();
        oodvm.InvoiceDetailsSingelLine = bla5.FirstOrDefault();
        oodvm.SingelRMAAntals = bla6.FirstOrDefault();
        return View(oodvm);

       }
```

RMAHistory ViewModel:

```
public class RMAHistory
    {

   public SingelRMAAntal SingelRMAAntals { get; set; }

        public class SingelRMAAntal
        {

            public SingelRMAAntal()
            {



            }
            public SingelRMAAntal(string TotalRMA)
            {
                this.TotalRMA = TotalRMA;

            }


            public string TotalRMA { get; set; }

        }

    }
```

View:

```
@using NameSpace.Models
@model RMAHistory

<div class="content">
 <form id="RMAForm">

   <input type="text" id="Kundenavn" value="@Model.InvoiceDetailsSingelLine.Kundenavn">
   <br/>
   <input id="Ordrenummer" type="text" value="@Model.InvoiceDetailsSingelLine.Ordrenummer">
   <br/>

  if (Model.SingelRMAAntals.TotalRMA == null)

   {

     <div style="display:none;" class="col-md-3">

    <input name="Antal_RMA" id="Antal_RMA" value="@Model.SingelRMAAntals.TotalRMA">

    </div>

  }

    else
   {
        <div class="col-md-3">

       <input name="Antal_RMA" id="Antal_RMA" value="@Model.SingelRMAAntals.TotalRMA">

       </div>
   }


</form>
</div>
```

Comment: you much check the parent object first like so if (Model.SingelRMAAntals != null && Model.SingelRMAAntals.TotalRMA == null)

Comment: @KevDevMan i did but i get same error : Object reference is not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: nest the queries. if (Model != null){ if (Model.SingelRMAAntals != null){ if (Model.SingelRMAAntals.TotalRMA == null){ /*** Put your code here ***/}}}

Comment: @mayowaogundele in Controller or in View ?!

Comment: In the View you have above.

Comment: @mayowaogundele god bless you man , its works , if you can post your anwser and i will mark it as right anwser :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your view to look like below

```
@using NameSpace.Models
    @model RMAHistory

    <div class="content">
     <form id="RMAForm">

       <input type="text" id="Kundenavn" value="@Model.InvoiceDetailsSingelLine.Kundenavn">
       <br/>
       <input id="Ordrenummer" type="text" value="@Model.InvoiceDetailsSingelLine.Ordrenummer">
       <br/>

     if (Model != null)
    {
        if (Model.SingelRMAAntals != null)
        {
            if (Model.SingelRMAAntals.TotalRMA == null)

            {

                <div style="display:none;" class="col-md-3">

                <input name="Antal_RMA" id="Antal_RMA" value="@Model.SingelRMAAntals.TotalRMA">

                </div>

            }

                else
            {
                    <div class="col-md-3">

                <input name="Antal_RMA" id="Antal_RMA" value="@Model.SingelRMAAntals.TotalRMA">

                </div>
            }

            }
     }
    </form>
    </div>
```